# Edit map to show specific area/location only

Tags: google-fusion-tables

I would like to know if there is an easy way to show only a specific location on the map for Google Fusion Tables.  For instance, I would only like the map to show the state of California.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible. You can make the Lat Lon of california and save it as csv files. Then google fusion table you can import it and also make a marker icon too. Hope that helps your question.